# Kubectl : No resource found even tough there are pods running in the namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have 2 pods running on default namespace as shown below

```
 NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
default       alpaca-prod                        1/1     Running   0             36m
default       alpaca-test                        1/1     Running   0             4m26s
kube-system   coredns-78fcd69978-xd7jw           1/1     Running   0             23h
```

But when I try to get deployments I do not see any

```
kubectl get deployments 
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Can someone explain this behavior ?

I am running k8 on Minikube.

Comment: you have deployments?? we can run pods without deployments too

Answer (score 1):

I think these are pods which were spawned without `Deployment`, `StatefulSet` or `DaemonSet`.

---

You can run pod like this using the command, e.g.:

```
kubectl run nginx-test --image=nginx -n default
```

---

pods created via `DaemonSet` usually end with `-xxxxx`

pods created via `Deployment` usually end with `-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx`

pods created via `StatefulSet` usually end with `-0`, `-1` etc.

pods created without upper resource, usually have exact name as you specified e.g. `nginx-test`, `nginx`, etc.

---

So my guess that is a standalone `Pod` resource (last option)